# YouTube Data API (v3, PHP) error on Heroku?

Tags: php, heroku, mamp, youtube-data-api

I am writing a PHP app that uses the YouTube Data API v3 ([link to Google-provided PHP client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)).  I'm testing it with MAMP and publishing with Heroku.  When I run the app with MAMP, it works fine, but when I deploy to Heroku, I get the following error message:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Google_Http_CacheParser' not found in /app/Google/IO/Abstract.php on line 165

The only difference I could think of was different PHP versions (MAMP 5.5.10, Heroku 5.6.10). But the problem was not solved after restricting this with `composer.json`.  Besides, Google claims that the client should work with any version 5.2.1+.

I am importing everything with the Google-provided `autoload.php`.

The code for the app is published [on GitHub](https://github.com/nicktendo64/brady-vs-grey-php). Only `update.php` uses the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

My .gitignore was ignoring all files that began with "cache."  This was added a long time ago, before I was using this version of the API.

Because of this, **Cache**Parser.php (one of the files in Google's PHP client) was never being sent to the server.